# Persistent global variable in linux shell

Tags: command-line, bash, shell-script, environment-variables, bash-scripting

I have a script that needs to "switch a light on" for other scripts in some cases for other scripts, and as the environmental variable is available only to child process inch which it was created, I am kind of forced to use files to remember a state information generated in other shell.
I am calling all scripts via incrontab and that means they they are not children of a single shell(if I am not mistaken).

Update: I have change the title from "Persistent environmental variable" to "Persistent global variable in linux shell"

Comment: You say, "I am kind of forced to use files to remember a state information" - what is the problem then with persistent environment variable? Why can't you save it in the file as you already do else?

Comment: @duDE Imagine that I have a Script B that should be executed at 9 P.M. and turn off the switch, if the switch is turned on, and there are a lot of independent scripts that can turn on the switch if it is not turned on.
I do not want to use a file for that, and as I understand exported variable is there until the  shell or it's children are alive. Also I would like to turn off the switch implicitly. As you can see, any advice is valuable.

Comment: @ZackTitan, I want to explicitly set the variable, with the bash_profile every script will create it's environment and reset it to the implicit value, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to adjust each script to avoid race conditions so you need to come up with some kind of locking mechanism.

You could use `/dev/shm` and just handle it like a file. This should be accessible from each shell. You will have to watch out for permissions. I don't think you have the option to have a shared variable among all instances of bash.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am aware of race conditions, I am sure that all the scripts will be executed with a slight delay, will se how that works, and only then will think of locking.

Comment: This sounds like a smart answer, but give me a tutorial on /dev/shm to force me choose your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Ok this is a correct answer, but as my application will not cause high loads, I will use a regular file, I am going to write 1 or 0 or maybe a timestamp into it once in few seconds. Thanks a lot.